# Use a method declared outside of ES6 React Component class

Tags: javascript, oop, reactjs

I have this code below with reactjs ES 6 but it does not work. My question is: how to use a method outside the component class ? And is it possible to have many components classes in a single file? Thanks a lot.

```
function methodOutside(){
   /** Do something else **/  
}

class myComponent1 extends React.Component{
  constructor(){
    super();
    this.methodInside1 = this.methodInside1.bind(this);
  }

  methodInside(){

   /**Do something **/
  }

  render(){
     this.methodInside1();
     methodOutside();
  }

}

class myComponent2 extends React.Component{
  constructor(){
    super();
    this.methodInside2 = this.methodInside2.bind(this);
  }

  methodInside(){

   /**Do something **/
  }

  render(){
     this.methodInside2();
     methodOutside();
  }

}
```

Comment: *"how to use a method outside the component class ?"* Exactly like you have it. Only that we would simply call it a "function", not a "method". *"And is it possible to have many components classes in a single file?"* Yes. *"...but it does not work"* You should elaborate on that.

Comment: Yes, please elaborate the errors your are getting from the code. This looks like it would work - so we don't have all the information to help out.

Comment: `this.methodInside2 = this.methodInside2.bind(this);` and `this.methodInside1 = this.methodInside1.bind(this);` you seem to be calling `bind` on something that is undefined. Didn't you mean `this.methodInside1 = this.methodInside.bind(this);`

Comment: OMG I saw @BrenoFerreira ... thanks so much ... how come everybody missed it!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer I posted in the comments. Posting it here so it's easier for everyone else to see it.

`this.methodInside2 = this.methodInside2.bind(this);` and `this.methodInside1 = this.methodInside1.bind(this);` you seem to be calling bind on something that is undefined. Didn't you mean `this.methodInside1 = this.methodInside.bind(this);`

Although I can't see the point of doing this, since you can just call `this.methodInside()` from the `render()` method. `this` will be bound just as you'd expect.